# lighttpd, php, fastcgi - individual virtual host settings for notices warnings and error showing

Tags: php, lighttpd, error-reporting, virtual-hosts

I am looking for a way to configure the virtual hosts on a lighttpd individually to show or not Errors and Warnings.

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
```

I like to make it from the virtual hots configuration. Not from the php.ini.

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "domain1\.com" {
            server.document-root = "/home/lighttpd/domain1.com/http"
            accesslog.filename   = "/home/lighttpd/domain1.com/logs/access.log"

            php_flag display_errors On ....???

}
```

If you try the Code above you get the following Errors

```
root@web:~/lighttpd# /etc/init.d/lighttpd restart
2014-02-05 11:23:54: (configfile.c.932) source: /usr/share/lighttpd/mysql_vhost.py line: 8 pos: 24 parser failed somehow near here: display_errors
2014-02-05 11:23:54: (configfile.c.932) source: /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf line: 32 pos: 1 parser failed somehow near here: (EOL)
```

is there any other way to talk to PHP from inside lighttpd ?
PHP is loaded as a module.
It should be one.

Comment: I found htscanner from pecl. But I don't understand it yet.

Comment: okay, I installed it, and it's working, but I do not want to solve it from the .htaccess .. i want to make it from the virtual host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, are looking for something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domains/example.com/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/domains/example.com/apache.error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/domains/example.com/apache.access.log common
    php_flag log_errors on
    php_flag display_errors on
    php_value error_reporting 30719
    php_value error_log /var/www/domains/example.com/php.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

The reason `30719` is used is below

All errors and warnings, as supported, except of level `E_STRICT` prior to `PHP 5.4.0.   32767 in PHP 5.4.x`, `30719 in PHP 5.3.x`, `6143 in PHP 5.2.x`, `2047` previously . 
Read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) for this.

You can use

```
php_value error_reporting 2147483647
```

The above number, according to documentation should enable 'all' errors irrespective of version, if you want a more granular setting, manually OR the values together, or run

Or see below

```
php_value error_reporting 6143 # for all errors notice, warnings, etc
php_value error_reporting 6135 #show warnings less strict
```

Comment: that's the apache syntax. I am looking for the lighttpd syntax. More or less the same you wrote here, just for lighttpd.

Comment: ONE MORE TIME. You can not put this kind of stanzas (php_flag log_errors on ...) into a lighttpd virtual host. You get a error.

`root@web:~/lighttpd# /etc/init.d/lighttpd restart
2014-02-05 11:23:54: (configfile.c.932) source: /usr/share/lighttpd/mysql_vhost.py line: 8 pos: 24 parser failed somehow near here: log_errors
2014-02-05 11:23:54: (configfile.c.932) source: /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf line: 32 pos: 1 parser failed somehow near here: (EOL)`

Answer (score 0):

If PHP is running as module under lighttpd than you can put below code inside virtualhost configuration :-

```
  php_flag display_errors off
```

Comment: Answer by @deonia is going to be more helpful.

Comment: The configuration example is already given by Deonia. You need to put this inside VirtualHost tags..

Comment: Wo is @deonia ? And what did he post ?

Comment: this solution is not working with lighttpd, it works with apache2